Algebraic theorems with no known algebraic proofs
What are some good examples of algebraic theorems that have no known algebraic proofs?
A few I know concern classifications of (not necessarily associative) division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$: the theorem due to Hopf that the only commutative ones have dimensions 1 or 2 (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$); and the theorem due to Kervaire/Milnor that the only (not necessarily commutative) ones have dimensions 1, 2, 4, or 8 (like $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{H}$, or $\mathbb{O}$). At least, the Wikipedia page on suggests there are not known algebraic proofs of these theorems: all known proofs use topology or geometry.

Fundamental theorem of algebra?

@J.W.Tanner There are algebraic proofs which only use two facts from analysis: Real polynomials of odd degree have a real root, and each complex number has a complex square root. At some point an algebraic proof has to use the definition or easy properties of real or complex numbers.

Indeed, it has been remarked that the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra is neither fundamental nor a theorem of algebra

I don’t believe there are any purely algebraic proofs of Gromov’s theorem that groups of polynomial growth have a nilpotent subgroup of finite index.

I believe that the proofs that torsion-free groups of cohomological dimension 1 are at least somewhat topological or geometric, although I’m not sure where you put the dividing line between algebra and combinatorial topology.

@BenjaminSteinberg are you missing some words in your second comment? The proofs that "torsion-free groups of cohomological dimension 1" what?

Yes, it should say are free

There is an important semigroup operation $+$ defined on the set of ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$. It is an important and nontrivial theorem that there are non-principal ultrafilters $u$ for which $u+u = u$. The statement of this theorem, and all of the relevant definitions, can be expressed without any reference to any topology on the set of ultrafilters. But every proof of the theorem that I know involves topology in a nontrivial way. (I'm putting this as a comment, rather than an answer, because I imagine it might stretch too far what you mean by an "algebraic theorem.")

@WillBrian, this seems equivalent to the statement that every compact right topological semigroup has an idempotent so I'm not sure how a nontopological proof can be expected

@BenjaminSteinberg: Yes, I agree. I expect that any proof of this theorem needs to make use of the topology on $\beta \mathbb N$, either openly or sneakily. That's what makes it a good example of what the OP is asking for (unless it's dismissed as not "real algebra" and more set theory).

@WillBrian, my point is that if $\beta \mathbb N$ has idempotents so does every other compact right topological semigroup because it is free on one generator in this category

I'm going to politely disagree with the example in the post: at least for associative division algebras, their classification is essentially the computation that $\operatorname{Br}(\mathbf R) \cong \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, which is easy to prove using Galois cohomology: $H^2(\mathbf R,\mathbf C^\times) \cong \hat H{}^0(\mathbf R,\mathbf C^\times) = \mathbf R^\times/N(\mathbf C^\times)$. I consider this an algebraic proof. That said, I have no idea if Galois cohomology tells you anything about non-associative algebras.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn but the theorems are about not necessarily associative algebras, right? Am I misunderstanding your comment?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401542 where some related results are discussed. But if there really are purely algebraic proofs of these theorems of Hopf and Kervaire/Milnor, I would be quite interested to know that (and the Wikipedia page could be updated).

A former example: every subgroup of a surface group is a surface group (if finite index) or free (if infinite index). This was well-known by topological means for a long time (certainly Klein and Fricke knew it) but only given an algebraic proof in the 1970s.

Is there a purely algebraic definition for "totally real number field" ?

Ah I see. If you really insist on non-associative algebras, you are probably right that there is no algebraic proof. The associative case is apparently due to Frobenius, for which there are many proofs, including many algebraic ones.

do proofs from motivic homotopy theory count?

Can people here please stop adding their answers in the comment section and instead post them as answers? Thanks.

Here is my favorite one (though not so elementary).

Theorem (Grothendieck). Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Then, the etale fundamental group $\pi^{\rm et}_1(X)$ is topologically finitely generated.

Note that $k$ might have characteristic $p$. Nevertheless, all known proofs of this fact eventually reduce to the case of a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$, and use the comparison theorem with the topological fundamental group.
An algebraic proof of the topological finite generation is not known even for the prime-to-$p$ completion of $\pi_1^{\rm et}(X)$. I think we know how to reduce this possibly easier question to the special case of the single (non-projective) variety $X= \mathbb{P}^1_k \setminus \{0,1,\infty\}$. Still, even in this case we need the complex numbers!
(For $\ell$-adic cohomology, there are general algebraic proofs of finite dimensionality. But not for the fundamental group!)

Do you maybe mean “topologically finitely generated”?

@Aphelli yes. In my defence, I am not the only one using "finitely generated" to mean "topologically finitely generated" in the context of pro-finite groups.

... which makes sense since you just apply the notion of being finitely generated to the given category of topological groups. Adding adjectives is only required when forgetful functors are, well, forgotten (here from topological groups to groups). Anyway, great example!

Is "topologically finitely generated" really an algebraic property?

@PeterMueller That's problematic since finite index subgroups might not be open if the group is not topologically finitely generated.

An example comes from the connection of function fields and Riemann surfaces: Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, $t$ a variable, and $L/K(t)$ be a finite Galois extension. Then for each place $p_i$ of $K(t)$ which is ramified in $L$ there is a place $P_i$ of $L$ above $p_i$ whose (cyclic) inertia group is generated by $\sigma_i$ such that the following holds:

The Galois group of $L/K(t)$ is generated by the $\sigma_i$.
$\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_r=1$.

As far as I know, the only way to prove this purely algebraic statement is to first reduce it to $K=\mathbb C$, and then reformulate it in terms of a branched covering of compact Riemann surfaces and making use of the fundamental group of a punctured Riemann sphere.
The converse, by the way, holds too, and relies on the same translation.
Added 2024-11-22: David Harbater's beautiful survey article Riemann’s Existence Theorem details the failed attempts to prove either direction algebraically, and also discusses weaker results which were shown algebraically using formal schemes or rigid analytic geometry (like Florian Pop's Half Riemann’s Existence Theorem) over more general fields.

Since there exist some simply ramified covers of given degree and (even) branch degree by direct computation, it suffices to prove that the parameter space of simply ramified covers by irreducible curves with given (even) branch degree is irreducible (i.e., connected, since this parameter space is smooth).  This parameter space is compactified by the moduli space of admissible covers, which is also smooth and proper, and has good reduction away from small primes.  Thus, by Deligne's solution of the Weil conjectures, we are reduced to Malle's conjecture for function fields . . .

@JasonStarr Can you elaborate on the first step of your argument? I don't follow it. How do you deduce this statement from a property of simply ramified covers?

@WillSawin Every finite, generically etale morphism is a specialization of "simply ramified covers" (by the infinitesimal deformation theory of finite, generically etale morphisms of smooth, projective curves).  There are specialization theorems for the etale fundamental group in SGA 1 (if necessary, make a finite base change of your trait so that the ramification divisor is a union of sections over the trait).

@JasonStarr I'm a little lost at what you do next. The issue is that the statement we want has the form "for each ramification point, there exists a point in the fiber over that point" which seems to become a stronger statement when multiple ramification points collide: Before they collide we could make different choices for the different points but after we are forced to make the same choice.

@WillSawin No, as I suggested, make a base change of your trait so that the ramification divisor is a union of sections.  Choose a representative of the conjugacy class for each ramification point in the generic fiber for each section.  Then, as the sections coalesce, take the composition of the corresponding representatives.

@WillSawin Perhaps you are suggesting that Grothendieck's proof of the specialization theorem for etale fundamental groups actually uses the comparison theorem, and so my argument is circular.  I do not think so.  My recollection is that Grothendieck only states the comparison theorem after proving the specialization theorem.

@JasonStarr In the case of symmetric groups, I can choose $(12)$ as the representative of each conjugacy class for a simply ramified cover. Then the composition of the corresponding representatives will definitely not be in the right conjugacy class for a higher-order ramification point when I specialize to a non-simply ramified cover. My concern is not with the specialization theorem.

@WillSawin What?  There are some number of ramification sections specializing on the special fiber.  For each ramification section, the formal completion along the ramification section is (formally) a squaring map that has "two branches".  You use the transposition of those two branches.  You do not get to call the branches whatever you want and have different branches get the same name.  If you prefer, we can work with the monoidal category of etale covers over the complement of the ramification divisor if that makes things clearer.

@WillSawin By the way, the statement in the answer is technically incorrect (but easily fixed).  For some branch points $p_i$ in the codomain $\mathbb{P}^1$, the cycle type of $\sigma_i$ for that branch point is not necessary a single cycle.  It can have any nontrivial cycle type consistent with the Deligne-Simpson-(Hurwitz) problem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12758/deligne-simpson-problem-in-the-symmetric-group

@JasonStarr Where does the answer say that the $\sigma_i$'s are single cycles? In order to formulate things without need to pass to a Galois closure, I assumed that $L/K(t)$ is Galois. So in fact each $\sigma_i$ is a product of cycles of the same length with respect to the regular action of $\text{Gal}(L/K(t))$.

The answer says that there is a single geometric point $P_i$ above $p_i$ and an element in the inertia group of $P_i$.  By the theory of Puiseux series, such $\sigma_i$ is a single cycle.

@JasonStarr I'm not a native speaker of English, but when I say that "there is a place $P_i$ [$\ldots$] above $p_i$", I don't mean to say that $P_i$ is the only one. In fact, by some kind of Chinese remainder theorem argument, $\text{Gal}(L/K(t))$ acts transitively on the places of $L$ above $p_i$. The point is that the two properties in the answer only hold if one picks the right places and generators of its inertia groups (which in this case equals the decomposition groups, because $K$ is algebraically closed).

@JasonStarr Based on Peter Mueller's comment it seems the source of our confusion may be that we are reading the answer in different ways. I interpreted it the same way as Peter Mueller did, producing a statement which is correct but I believe requires a topological proof. You interpreted it as a statement which, as you point out, is incorrect, but then sketched an argument to establish a corrected version. What is the corrected version?

@JasonStarr For a degree $n$ cover with monodromy group $S_n$ and $k$ branch points, the statement is that there exists a tuple of $k$ permutations that generate $S_n$, whose product is $1$, and such that the cycle type of the $i$'th permutation agrees with the ramification type of the $i$'th branch point. For a simply branched cover, the statement is trivial, and no connectedness assumption is needed: The number of branch points is even and at least $2n-2$ by Riemann-Hurwitz, and we can just produce a single example for $k=2n-2$ and extend it trivially to higher values of $k$.

@JasonStarr So if your argument works as I understand it, it would work with no assumption on Malle's conjecture at all and with no geometric input other than the specialization theorem.

@WillSawin I have no idea how to prove Malle's conjecture.  I believe that Ellenberg and Venkatesh worked on this, but possibly (probably) their proof uses the comparison theorem and the usual presentation of the topological fundamental group.  I am simply saying that there is a strategy to reduce the statement to the statement of Malle's conjecture (which is a purely algebraic / analytic-number-theoretic statement).

@JasonStarr Your argument has the form "Property P holds for one simply-branched cover. If it holds for one simply-branched cover, it holds for all covers in the same connected component. Assuming Malle's conjecture, the moduli space of simply-branched covers is simply connected, so property P holds for all simply-branched covers. By a specialization argument, property P holds for all covers." But what is property P?

@JasonStarr I don't understand your point. I formulated a known theorem in purely algebraic terms of function fields. And as far as I know, there is no other proof than to reduce it to $K=\mathbb C$ (by first showing that one can replace $K$ by some suitable finitely generated field (which depends on $L$ of course), and then imbed this field into $\mathbb C$), and then use techniques from Riemann surfaces.

So I do not see the merit of reducing a purely algebraically formulated theorem to a purely algebraically formulated conjecture.

Malle's conjecture is about counting points of a variety (a scheme of admissible covers a la Harris-Mumford and S. Mochizuki) over  finite fields.  Many such conjectures are proved by techniques of analytic number theory, e.g., the Hardy-Littlewood circle method.  I do not know if Malle's conjecture has been proved that way, but I believe that it could be proved that way.  So that gives an approach to proving this result about (tamely ramified) etale fundamental groups of smooth affine curves that does not use the comparison with the topological fundamental group (over the complex numbers).

@WillSawin  I just noticed your most recent comment.  Property P, as noted by Peter Mueller, is that for each ordering of the (geometric) branch points, for each branch point $p_i$ of the codomain, there exists a generator $\sigma_i$ of the inertia group at $p_i$ of the Galois group of the cover such that the product of the elements $\sigma_i$ in the Galois group equals the identity (the elements satisfy the Deligne-Simpson-Hurwitz condition).

@JasonStarr The Deligne-Simpson-Hurwitz condition is usually formulated with the existence of a generator of a conjugate of the inertia group at $p_i$. This removes the need to specify an embedding of the inertia group into the Galois group, i.e. it removes base point issues. Without putting the conjugate in, the issue is that it's not clear how to specify a path from the base point to the ramification point in an algebraic way and if you did not clear why the condition would be stable under algebraic deformations. With the conjugate, the issue is that the specialization argument doesn't work

@WillSawin  I guess that I could also specify that the representatives of the conjugacy classes generate the Galois group (this is equivalent to saying that the cover is connected).  This eliminates the objection you raised that we could just choose all of the (even) number of transpositions to be equal.

@JasonStarr You can just choose pairs of transpositions that cancel but not the same transposition each time, like $(12)(12)(23)(23) ... (n-1n)(n-1n)$. We always have at least $2n-2$ branch points if the branch points are simple so this always works.

@WillSawin There is a parameter space $\mathbb{P}^{2b}$ of degree $2b$ effective divisors in $\mathbb{P}^1$.  There is a discriminant hypersurfaces of degree $2(b-1)$.  Over the open complement $U$ there is a finite etale cover $\widetilde{U}$ parameterizing finite flat morphisms of degree $d$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ that are etale over the complement of the divisor of degree $2b$ and with “simple branching” over the $2b$ points.  Denote by $V$ the open complement of the divisor of relative degree $2b$ in $\widetilde{U}\times_{U}\mathbb{P}^1$ . . .

@WillSawin . . .  There is a finite etale cover of $V$ that is the etale open in the universal finite flat cover.  The Galois group $G$ of this cover surjects onto the Galois group $H$ of $\widetilde{U}$ over $U$.  This induces an action of $H$ on the kernel.  We require the “Hurwitz system” of transpositions generating the Galois groups is compatible with the $H$-action.  I am asserting that it is also compatible with the (partial) compactification by admissible covers.  The analysis along the boundary strata gives the “specialization argument” that no outlined above.

@JasonStarr The finite etale cover of $V$ is not Galois over he complement of the relative divsior of degree $2b$ in $U \times \mathbb P^1$. The kernel of the map from the Galois group of the Galois closure to $H$ will be a subgroup of a product of copies of $G$, and that is what $H$ acts on. But what compatibility do you want? The action of $H$ is the action of the braid group. The action of braids does not send the generators of local monodromy groups to themselves but rather permutes and conjugates them.

@JasonStarr Just specifying that the action sends these elements to conjugates of themselves up to appropriate permutation seems too lax: Everything conjugate to a. given inertia element will be sent to something conjugate to that inertia element. But specifying which element of the braid group sends an element to which conjugate requires explicitly describing the generators of the braid group, i.e. requires topology.

@WillSawin Yes, it conjugates them.  A “Hurwitz datum” is a simultaneous conjugacy class of an ordered sequence of transpositions whose product is trivial and that (collectively) generate the Galois group.

@JasonStarr For each place $p_i$ there is a conjugacy class $C_i$ of inertia generators. If one picks $\sigma_i\in C_i$ arbitrarily, the group $A$ generated by the $\sigma_i$'s need not be the full Galois group $G$. (Only the normal closure $B$ of $A$ equals $G$, because the fixed field of $B$ is an unramified extension of $K(t)$, hence equal to $K(t)$.) I still believe that there is no way to see that the $\sigma_i$'s can be chosen such that they generate $G$ and (after fixing an order) that their product is $1$ without using paths which generate the fundamental group of a punctured sphere.

@PeterMueller  You might be right.  I remember that when I was a graduate student some of us read Mochizuki's paper.  At that point I was fairly convinced one could deduce the basic statements about the (tamely ramified) etale fundamental groups of semistable pointed curves via transitivity of Galois actions (which can be proved by point-counting over finite fields) and specialization.

I just came across a survey article (reference added to my answer) by David Harbater which should clarify what I had tried to explain.

I do not quite understand Harbater's survey. He says that a difficulty is to define the correspondence $i$. Let $S$ be a finite subset of (closed) $k$-points of $\mathbb P_k^1$, and $U:=\mathbb P_k^1\setminus S$ with a chosen base $k$-point $x\in U$. I think that finite étale Galois covers of $U$ one-to-one correspond to quotients of $\pi_1^{\textrm{ét}}(U)$? He says that the correspondence depends on "the choice of homotopy basis of $U$", but that appears in the identification of $\pi_1^{\textrm{ét}}(U)$ with the profinite completion of the free group?

Artin's theorem on positive polynomials, which solves Hilbert's 17th problem in the affirmative, apparently still has no algebraic proof.
Theorem (Artin): If $f \in \mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ is pointwise nonnegative, then it is a sum of squares in $\mathbb{R}(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.
Artin's proof uses quantifier elimination for real closed fields from model theory, so this arguably qualifies as not purely algebraic. As far as I know this is still the only successful approach to the problem.

What about the paper by Hillar and Nie, An elementary and constructive solution to Hilbert's 17th problem for matrices?

@TimothyChow: I don't know that paper, but from a quick look it seems that they already assume Artin's theorem for their proof.

Is it the same for any Postivstellensatz? Is this model-theoretic proof comparable to that of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, or Chevalley's theorem of constructibility?

Is this really an algebraic theorem if positivity is involved?

@AntoineLabelle Over the real numbers, nonnegative is equivalent to being the square of a real number, so "nonnegative" can be defined algebraically.

@AntoineLabelle This theorem is true (and by Artin) if you replace $\mathbb R$ by any real-closed field, and in this sense, it is also algebraic.

Some little effort is needed to formulate "takes non-negaitive values" in algebraic terms. Sure, it means that values are positive (=are squares), but one needs to formulate what it means to evaluate a rational function. This should be doable by considering homomorphisms from finitely generated subalgebras to the reals.

Evaluation of any polynomial of degree $n$ is equivalently an element $\text{Hom}{\mathbf{CRing}}(\mathbb{R}[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n],\mathbb{R})$, which is in natural bijection with $\text{Hom}{\mathbf{Set}}({X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n},\mathbb{R})$.

There should be many examples in algebraic number theory, as it often interacts nontrivially with analytic number theory. For example, I am pretty sure there is no algebraic proof of Bauer's theorem (but would love to be proved wrong):
Theorem (Bauer, 1903) Let $K \to L$ and $K \to M$ be finite Galois extensions of number fields, and assume that a prime $\mathfrak p \subseteq \mathcal O_K$ is totally split in $L$ if and only if it is totally split in $M$. Then $L \cong M$.
This follows pretty easily from the Chebotarev density theorem (or Kronecker's split version, see Corollary 2.4 of these notes by Keith Conrad).
It's not just the proof of the Chebotarev density theorem that uses analytic number theory, somehow the statement itself is analytic in nature. But its corollaries, such as Bauer's theorem, may be purely algebraic statements. (I would not be surprised if there were other key theorems with these attributes, for instance in geometric group theory.)

What about Minkowski’s bound to calculate the class number?

In “Field Arithmetic” it is quite common to use the Cebotarev Density Theorem to deduce irreducibility theorems that are purely algebraic statements.  Some of these can be proved purely algebra-geometrically (I have a paper about this).

The Scott-Wiegold conjecture posits that the free product of three non-trivial cyclic groups can never be normally generated by a single element.
It was eventually proven by Jim Howie, by studying the homotopy theory of the representation variety of $F_3$ in $SU_2$.
Similar uses of homotopy theory to solve purely algebraic problems:

The finite group case of the Kervaire conjecture.

The non-freeness of the module $A^3/\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)$, where $A=\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/\langle 1-x^2-y^2-z^2\rangle$, usually proved via the Hairy Ball theorem.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y,t]/\langle 1-x^2-y^2\rangle$.  Then the elements $$\alpha= x+(1-t^2)a,\\ \beta=yt+(1-t^2)b,$$ can never generate $R$ as an ideal, for any $a,b\in R$.  Easily proved by considering the winding numbers  (at $t=1$ and $t=-1$) of $(\alpha,\beta)$ about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as $(x,y)$ goes round the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.



A conjecture doesn't "ask" something, it rather asserts a strong expectation that something holds true.

@YCor It turns out that in this case that strong expectation was in the correct direction.  I have edited accordingly.

number 2 here is one of my favorites, and perhaps is due to Swan.

The proof (by Hecke I believe) that in a number field the ideal class of
the different is always the square of a class.

A related MO page:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28776/does-the-ideal-class-of-the-different-of-a-number-field-have-a-canonical-squar

It's been a long while since I've read that proof, what sort of non-algebraic inputs does it use?

The fundamental theorem of algebra   states that every non-constant single-variable polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb C$ has at least one complex root; i.e., the field of complex numbers is algebraically closed. Known proofs involve some mathematical analysis, or at least the topological concept of continuity.

One could perhaps quibble that there is no "purely algebraic" definition of $\mathbb{C}$.

@TimothyChow I wonder if there's actually a robust way to define what a 'purely algebraic' definition is, because obviously $\mathbb{C}$ is the unique algebraically closed field with characteristic $0$ and transcendence degree $2^{\aleph_0}$, which doesn't strictly speaking refer to topology.
Maybe in some sense the issue is that algebraic (or at least 'combinatorial') constructions of algebraically closed fields are in some sense highly non-canonical, whereas $\mathbb{C}$ of course has a specific topological construction.

@JamesEHanson Well if you define $\mathbb{C}$ this way, then you can argue it is an algebraic definition (one can still debate over whether the cardinality requirement is is an algebraic notion of not), but then the fundamental theorem of algebra has a pretty obvious "algebraic" proof...

Yes, if $\mathbb{C}$ is defined to be an algebraically closed field, then the "theorem" that it's algebraically closed is trivial. In any case, I doubt that there can be a truly satisfying way to robustly define "algebraic definition" or "algebraic theorem" or "algebraic proof."

Can't you define $\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb R^2$ with a strange multiplication. That seems purely algebraic to me.

@user479223 How do you define $\mathbb{R}$ in a purely algebraic manner?

@TimothyChow Lol, fine. I get your point.

$\mathbb{R}$ is strange because it is 'algebraically unique' in the sense that it's rigid and therefore determined up to unique isomorphism, but there's seemingly no direct algebraic or categorical construction of it among rings or fields. (And this is true of all of the local fields of characteristic $0$ except $\mathbb{C}$.)

But isn't $\mathbb R$ easily singled out among ordered fields (as the order-complete, Archimedean ordered field), and can't ordered fields reasonably be considered part of algebra?

@LSpice Yes, it is the maximal Archimedean ordered field, but you do have to show that such a thing exists. (In particular, you would need to show that the category of Archimedean ordered fields is essentially small, posetal, and closed under directed colimits.) I think you could reason about that in a way that feels 'more algebraic,' but in some sense it's going to be very similar the normal construction of $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps that's just part of what's so special about $\mathbb{R}$; its algebraic and topological properties are very tightly intertwined.

@JamesEHanson, re, sure, sorry; although the placement of my comment made it unclear, I was meaning to respond more to what I took to be ‍@‍TimothyChow's implicit claim that there was no purely algebraic definition of $\mathbb R$ (which I took to mean 'characterisation', not 'construction', in the spirit of your definition/characterisation of $\mathbb C$).

@LSpice Well, I guess I was implicitly thinking about a construction. I don't normally think of the fundamental theorem of algebra as stating that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed if it exists.

Maybe Artin's proof via Galois theory is algebraic enough.

Are there other algebraic characterizations of ℂ which don't explicitly say it is algebraically closed?

I think one should not conflate constructing an object and showing that the constructed object indeed coincides with the desired object, and deducing properties from an already defined object. The former is the business of the fundamental theorem of algebra: we construct $\mathbb{C}$ using analysis and show that it is algebraically closed as expected. The only well-posed question is thus, whether there is an alternative characterisation of $\mathbb{C}$ in "purely algebraic terms" not "explicitly encompassing" the algebraic closedness of $\mathbb{C}$. This does not seem very well-posed...

@TimothyChow One possible criterion would be Galois invariance.

@TimothyChow I would actually be pretty satisfied with a "purely algebraic" proof that "The degree two extension of any complete Archimedean ordered field is algebraically closed" and cordons off analysis purely to the existence statement. This seems hard though!

@TimothyChow Here is a purely algebraic definition of $\mathbb{R}$: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0301015.  A purely algebraic definition of $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$.  It is a field because $X^2+1$ is irreducible over the field $\mathbb{R}$.  The challenge is to give an algebraic proof that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.

On a related note, the ring of $p$-adic integers can be constructed algebraically as $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/(p-X)$, and, just as $\mathbb{R}$  is isomorphic to the ring $\text{QEnd}(\mathbb{Z})$ of all quasi-endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$, the ring of adeles over $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\text{QEnd}(\mathbb{Q})$.  See https://studenttheses.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A3596357/view

@JamesEHanson Someone has done the work of algebraically establishing the properties of the class of Archimedean fields to show there is a maximal one and has the usual completeness proeprty: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fb1pNJVMuROmpLq-kDwXXeY2QxzCV0hy/view

Can we please stop pretending that in all these examples there is anything particular algebraic but non-topological, or the opposite? Things like formal power series, ordered fields, classes of slopes, quasi-isometries cannot be tagged with "algebra" XOR "topology".

Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression: if $a$ and $b$ are any relatively prime positive integers, then there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $a+nb$ for positive integers $n$.
EDIT, given @SamHopkins comment: Dirichlet's theorem, states, equivalently, that a linear polynomial in the UFD $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ represents infinitely many irreducible elements of the UFD $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if the polynomial is nonconstant and irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. One can also include the generalization of Dirichlet's theorem to number fields.  Dirichlet's unit theorem is another example.

Is this really an "algebraic theorem"?

@SamHopkins Well, $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial object in the category of rings, it is a UFD, primes (and their negatives) are those  integers that generate the nonzero prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$, arithmetic sequences are algebraically defined, and there being infinitely many in such a sequence is, arguably, also an algebraic notion (meaning "not finite").  I include theorems of number theory that don't refer to analytic objects as "algebraic."  Another such theorem would be the classification of primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$ for a fixed integer $n$.

Abelian groups, for example, are  equivalently $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, which implies that any theorem about abelian groups is arguably a theorem about the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

And fundamental theorem of algebra is a theorem about polynomials over the field $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}/(X^2+1)$, while Dirichlet's theorem is about linear polynomials over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.  I don't see why one should be an "algebraic theorem" and not the other.

But in which sense it does not have algebraic proof?

@FedorPetrov I was unaware of any.  I suppose this is relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16735/is-a-non-analytic-proof-of-dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-known-or-possible

@JesseElliott I do not think that it makes sense to think of the Eudoxos reals as being an "algebraic" construction of $\mathbb{R}$. Taking equivalence classes of infinite sequences is about as analytic as it gets. At least, it is not more algebraic than the Cauchy construction, which also uses equivalence classes of infinite sequences.

@JannikPitt Cauchy's construction uses the analytic definitions of Cauchy and limit-zero sequences. The notion of an almost homomorphism of abelian groups is an algebraic one.  Abelian groups form an additive category Qab with morphisms as the quasi-homomorphisms. $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ is an algebraic object, also, not an analytic one, and the ring of $p$-adic integers can be constructed as $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/(p-X)$.  I'm not sure how that's any different. I think, by your argument, the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is an algebraic object,  but $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ is not.

@JesseElliott I would say the fundamental theme of analysis is making approximations exact. In both the Cauchy and the Eudoxos construction we have different approximations to the same ideal real number. The analytic step is in identifying these approximations by a suitable equivalence relation. It is precisely the equivalence relation where the analytic idea of making approximations exact appears. On the other hand, to define a ring of formal power series, one need not quotient by any equivalence relation, because there are not any approximations around.

@FedorPetrov In the sense that no one has produced one, at least not in full generality. I don't think one is known even for something like primes of the form $7n+3$, say.

@JannikPitt But then, $\mathbb Z_p=\mathbb Z[![T]!]/(p-T)$ is "making approximation exact" as well, and there is a similar realization of real numbers by a quotient of convergent Laurant series $\mathbb Z(!(T)!)_{>r}$ by Harbater's theorem.

@JannikPitt If $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ is a purely algebraic structure if both $R$ and $I$ are algebraically defined.  Moreover, if $R$ is a commutative ring and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation such that $R/\sim$ is a ring such that the projection from $R$ to $R/\sim$ is a ring homomorphism, then $R/\sim , = R/I$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$.  Since $R$ and $\sim$ are defined algebraically in the case of almost homomorphisms, all of this implies that the Eudoxus construction of $\mathbb{R}$ is an algebraic one.

@JesseElliott Please explain why your $I$ is algebraic. This surely should mean something like it being definable on the first-order language of rings. However, by Löwenheim-Skolem, there cannot be such an algebraic description of $\mathbb{R}$: there is a field satisfying all first order properties of fields of $\mathbb{R}$, which lies strictly between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. The equivalence relation of the Eudoxos reals really transcends the algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$, as does the equivalence relation induced by the Cauchy construction transcend $\mathbb{Q}$.

@JannikPitt BTW, I presume these comments should have been in response to my comment on the fundamental theorem of algebra reply, rather than this post about Dirichet's theorem. But anyway, for Eudoxus reals, $I$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself that are $0$ outside some finite subset of  $\mathbb{Z}$. Certainly that is an "algebraic" notion. In fact, it is a purely "discrete math" notion. By your argument, any uncountable ring would have no algebraic description, and that would include rings like $\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{F}_2$.

Also, by the upward Lowenhem-Skolem theorem, any first-order theory of $\mathbb{Z}$ has models of arbitrarily large cardinality.  Whether or not an object has a first-order characterization has little to do with whether or not an object has an "algebraic" characterization.  Both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have perfectly respectable cateogorical second-order characterizations.

@JesseElliott Sorry, but my point is not infinite sets = analysis. For me, algebraic has a specific meaning related to groups, rings, fields, whether finite or not. In particular, the distinction is not discrete math vs analysis. Löwenheim-Skolem shows pretty clearly that in my interpretation, there is no algebraic construction of $\mathbb{R}$. I think we should just agree to disagree here!

@JannikPitt Ok, I agree that neither of us will convince the other.

Okninski proved that $M$ is a monoid and $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ such that the monoid algebra $KM$ is von Neumann regular, then $M$ is locally finite using analytic methods.  No algebraic proof is known.
Recall a ring $R$ is von Neumann regular if $\forall a\in R, \exists b\in R$ such that $aba=a$ and a monoid is locally finite if all its finitely generated submonoids are finite.
The proof is quite short.  Let $X$ be a finite subset of $M$.  We want the submonoid $\langle X\rangle$ is finite.  Let $a=\frac{1}{|X|+1}\sum_{x\in X} x\in \mathbb QM\subseteq KM$.  Let $b\in KM$ with $(1-a)b(1-a)=1-a$. The subfield $L$ of $K$ generated by the coefficients of $a,b$ is finitely generated and hence embeds in $\mathbb C$.  Thus we may view $1-a,a,b\in \mathbb CM$.   Now $\mathbb CM$ embeds in the Banach algebra $\ell_1M$. The element $a$ has $\ell_1$-norm $\|a\|_1<1$.  Thus in $\ell_1M$ we have that $1-a$ is a unit with inverse $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$.  We deduce that $b=(1-a)^{-1}$.  But $b$ has finite support whereas $(1-a)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$ has support the submonoid generated by $X$.  We conclude that $\langle X\rangle$ is finite.

What properties of the complex numbers are you using here?

I’m using completeness, that they have uncountable transcendence degree over the rationals and that they are algebraically closed.

@MartinBrandenburg, I guess I'm also using order properties of the real numbers since I need that the coefficients in $a$ are positive to guarantee the support of the geometric sum is the monoid generated by X

Infinitesimal Thurston Rigidity in Holomorphic Dynamics
This concerns eigenvalues of a natural operator on cohomology.
The statement is Galois invariant. The only known proof is not.
Algebraic proofs of algebraic theorems about algebraically closed fields
